# Execute script at each boot - OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt

I want to start a shell-script every startup of the *openWRT* Rooter. But moving it in the `etc/init.d` directory seems not to work. Want to delete one line in a specific file at every startup. But it does not work.

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
START=80
STOP=85
start(){
grep -vwE "password" /etc/config/glconfig > /etc/config/glconfig
}
```

What shall i do to execute this (and other) scripts at startup?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In openwrt if you want to run a script on boot you should do:

```
 /etc/init.d/cust_script enable
```

then reboot the device, it will be effect after reboot.

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer. Thats the solution. 

Addtional Question: Do you have an idea to take this action automatically? I have to restore backuped OpenWRT Konfigurations on a huge amount of routers. I doesn't want to go the way with the manual way and enable the init scripts in 100 routers...

Comment: Hi,Wich action you want to automatically? restrore the backup or enable the script? Can you give more details?

Comment: I want to restore backup files by hand. But i dont want to open SSH connection and put the enable command to each Router by hand.